# getting 203 with error when using vsts rest api

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

When I'm trying to create a new work item in VSTS with the `POST` request:

```
https://galilinetsky.visualstudio.com/Automatiom/_apis/wit/workitems/$Test%20Case?api-version=5.0-preview.2
```

I get the next response :

> Microsoft Internet Explorer's Enhanced Security Configuration is
>   currently enabled on your environment. This enhanced level of security
>   prevents our web integration experiences from displaying or performing
>   correctly. To continue with your operation please disable this
>   configuration or contact your administrator.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of windows you are using?

Comment: windows 10, i tried the same on windows 7

Comment: Do you use PAT?

Comment: I tried but it didn't help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure Devops 203 Non-Authoritative Information with REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58991603/azure-devops-203-non-authoritative-information-with-rest-api)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's mainly caused by the PAT format is incorrect.

Such as if I add colon `:` before the PAT, the REST API will return with 203.

[image]

Comment: I get the same problem with my GET/POST requests, but there is no colon before the Personal Access Token, and adding one to the PAT results in a 401 error (instead of a 203 error).

Answer (score 23):

The solution is to be found in a similar question: [Why I get Internet Explorer enhanced security error message in Chrome if I call VSO API from Angularjs SPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33498440/why-i-get-internet-explorer-enhanced-security-error-message-in-chrome-if-i-call)

[Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/383807/andy) writes

> the PAT has to be prefix[ed] by ":" before you base 64 encode it"

So the solution is:

1. Create a Personal Access Token
2. Add a colon (':') before it
3. Encode the new PAT (with the preceding colon) using Base 64

Et voila ! That PAT will no longer give you a 203 error.

Comment: Thanks for this. Would never have figured it out on my own!

Answer (score 1):

adding on to @numeratus
This question took awhile for me to get correctly on powershell. https://www.opentechguides.com/how-to/article/azure/201/devops-rest-powershell.html helped me greatly and a resulting simplified powershell request to azure apis

```
#enter your token in pat token
$pat = "xxx"

# Create header with PAT
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($pat)"))
$header = @{authorization = "Basic $token"}

#enter your url in projects url
$projectsUrl = "https://feeds.dev.azure.com/"
$projects = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $projectsUrl -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header
```