# Azure Devops 203 Non-Authoritative Information with REST API

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-api-apps

[image]

While calling a REST API for Azure DevOps I am getting an error `203 Non-Authoritative Information`.
Actually I want to trigger a release pipeline line with the help of REST API.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#start-a-release

Comment: Just wanted to check before the weekend what the status on this issue was? Is it succeed for you to use postman by follow the below steps? Appreciate for [marking it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) which will also help others in the community.

Comment: If anyone ever reads this in the future, `203` is not an error code, and azure shouldn't have used it as such.

Answer (score 21):

The 203 error code normally caused by an incorrect PAT format. Looks like you are probably failing authentication because the PAT did not be encoded with `base64` correctly.

Ensure the `TYPE` is **Basic Auth**, and input the **correct PAT format** into `Password`:

[image]

[Authorization of Postman](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/authorization/).

Comment: Thanks, the above solution worked but why I can't use "Bearer Token" or OAuth 2.0 with Azure DevOps

Answer (score 6):

```
Yes, we are passing the PAT wrongly.
```

Just another way of doing it, `COPY` the PAT encode that to base64 manually from a site like - https://www.base64encode.org/

> Note - make sure you add ":" as a `prefix` on PAT and then encode that.

Copy the encoded value to header on Authorization as mentioned -

[image]

Hope this will help a few, the only catch was to make sure we add the ":" on the mentioned position.

**Edit:** 
Why to add ":"?
It is the separator between the Username and Password. In the Official documentation you can see this pattern where the replacement happens with an empty string. [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=Windows#use-a-pat-in-your-code)

Comment: @eoeo the edited comment to add ":" was really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't manage to get the other answers here to work, but I found an answer that worked for me on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75525981/1563422).

Here's the full code to connect to DevOps and get work item #123:

```
import base64
import requests

devops_org = 'Your organization name - check your DevOps URL'
devops_project = 'Your project name - check your DevOps URL'
devops_token = 'Your PAT from DevOps'
workitem_id = 123

b64_token = base64.b64encode(f":{devops_token}".encode()).decode()
headers = { "Authorization": f"Basic {b64_token}" }
response = requests.get(f"https://dev.azure.com/{devops_org}/{devops_project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{workitem_id}?api-version=7.1", headers=headers)
```

One important note: You **MUST** use two different variable names! If on the final line of code you attempt to use `devops_token = base64...` then it will generate a different base64-encoded string every time!