# Azure DevOps REST API Produces 203 Non-Authoritative Information

Tags: azure-devops

I am using a Bearer Token (Acquired using Client Credentials oAuth Flow against the Azure AD) to authenticate against the DevOps API but it responds back with **203 Non-Authoritative Information** as shown in the attached screenshot.

API Used :
[https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{DevOps-Org}/_apis/Tokens/Pats?api-version=6.1-preview](https://vssps.dev.azure.com/%7BDevOps-Org%7D/_apis/Tokens/Pats?api-version=6.1-preview)

[image: Screenshot]

Has anyone came across this situation ? Requesting expert advise to overcome this.

Comment: I am facing same issue to list the pat token. Is it fixed ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure Devops 203 Non-Authoritative Information with REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58991603/azure-devops-203-non-authoritative-information-with-rest-api)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in a PAT as well in your request.
this page shows you how to create a PAT if you have not already: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=Linux

This page shows how you can pass in your PAT in your request using postman: [Azure Devops 203 Non-Authoritative Information with REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58991603/azure-devops-203-non-authoritative-information-with-rest-api)