# Get Request to Azure DevOps with Personal Access Token (PAT) using Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, python-requests, http-headers

I'm trying to make a get request to Azure DevOps.

I have the URL and the Personal_Access_Token. The URL was created following these intructions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/items/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1&tabs=HTTP#definitions , and it is working fine in the browser. It is possible to see the information of the file that I'm targeting.

However, when I execute the request in python:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer myPAT',
}

response = requests.get('exampleurl.com/content', headers=headers)
```

I'm getting the 203 response...

I have also try other options following this link [Python requests library how to pass Authorization header with single token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19069701/python-requests-library-how-to-pass-authorization-header-with-single-token) without success. Including these headers:

```
personal_access_token_encoded = base64.b64encode(personal_access_token.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')    
headers={'Authorization': 'Basic '+personal_access_token_encoded}

headers={'Authorization': 'Basic '+personal_access_token}
```

But in both cases still having the same response.

For sure I'm not considering something. What could be missing?

Answer (score 6):

My "gotcha", when experiencing this issue, was that I wasn't encoding a ":" concatenated to the beginning of the PAT string. Here is how I encoded the PAT token:

`encoded_pat = base64.b64encode((":" + pat).encode()).decode()`

Comment: You can ditch the extra parentheses and format the string, so `encoded_pat = base64.b64encode(f":{pat}".encode()).decode()`

Answer (score 3):

Hi error feedback 203 is about your invalid token.

So what is the authorization type of your request call?

For pat `headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic pat'}`
[image]

For bearer token `headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer MYREALLYLONGTOKENIGOT'}`
[image]

You could put your rest api in postman and `click` the code button at the right-side bar to overview the rest api into different script.
[image]

Comment: Hi Ceeno. Thanks for your reply. I've also tried  ('Basic '+ pat) and ('Basic '+b64enc(pat)) but I'm still getting the same 203 message

Comment: @d2907 remove the `+`, and put your pat token in the quotes

Answer (score 2):

For Azure DevOps API, you need to use Basic Auth instead of Baerear, providing only the PAT token **encoded in base64**.

Comment: Hi Marcos. Thanks for your reply. I've also tried that:
personal_access_token_encoded = b64encode(personal_access_token.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')
 'Authorization': 'Basic '+(personal_access_token_encoded )}
Still getting the same message